# AnyEvent::SMTP обрезает ответы от Google сервера

Tags: email, perl, gmail

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use utf8;

use AnyEvent;
use AnyEvent::SMTP 'sendmail';
use Data::Dumper;

sendmail
   from => 'abc@abc',
   to   => 'foobar@gmail.com',
   data => "Subject: Email",
   cb   => sub {
       if (my $ok = shift) {
           warn "Successfully sent";
       }
       if (my $err = shift) {
           warn "Failed to send: $err";
       }
   }   
;

AnyEvent->condvar->recv;
```

Выдаёт:

```
Failed to send: 421-4.7.0 [x.x.x.x      15] Our system has detected that this message is at abc.pl line 20.
```

Так понимаю, вторая и последующие строки (\n) ответа от сервера игнорируются данным модулем, можно ли это починить без правок основного модуля AnyEvent::SMTP?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В переменной `$AnyEvent::SMTP::Conn::QRNL` лежит регулярное выражение, которое определяет ограничитель, до которого читается сообщение от сервера. По умолчанию это `qr<\015?\012>`, то есть читается только первая строка. Можно сделать так:

```perl
local $AnyEvent::SMTP::Conn::QRNL = qr<\015?\012$>;
```

чтобы прочитать всё сообщение целиком.